# npm start command gives error in react native

Tags: react-native, expo

```
I have been using /programming react native app since last 2 months.
Always it used to work fine , I could code and run the simulator on my iphone . The environment details are as follows:
EXPO --version 3.1.2 ,     npm -v 6.9.0,     node -v12.4.0
```

Suddenly, yesterday when I started the project by command 'expo start' it did not start, got a message expo is not installed. Hence I installed expo cli.

Now I typed the command 'expo start', however it gives error 
It opens the Metro builder but stops with error

```
I am unable to start the project and continue coding the app

I tried following troubleshooting :
removed 'node_modules' folder , re-installed 'npm install' 
however the same issue persists.



Expected:
The project should start , I should be able to run the simulator in phone

Actual:
The project did not start with 'expo start'
```

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.1006]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Jituni>cd C:\Users\Jituni\bholmentorworld

C:\Users\Jituni\bholmentorworld>expo start
Starting project at C:\Users\Jituni\bholmentorworld
Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002
Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)
Error: Can't find react-native in package.json dependencies
Error: React Native is not installed. Please run `npm install` in your project directory.
Couldn't start project. Please fix the errors and restart the project.
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

this is the dependencies.

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.2.1",
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "firebase": "^6.4.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: please provide me your package.json. and open the cmd by administrator and type `expo --version`. and then provide me the expo version.

Comment: @Dragon White {
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint": "^6.2.1",
    "expo": "^33.0.0",
    "firebase": "^6.4.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4",
    "react-navigation": "^3.11.1"
  },

Comment: "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "private": true
}

Comment: I mean installed dependencies include react-native dependency.

Comment: C:\Users\Jituni\bholmentorworld>expo --version
3.1.2

Comment: @DragonWhite, please suggest what to do for "I mean installed dependencies include react-native dependency"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you hadn't installed the react-native in your dependencies.

**SOLUTION**

you should make the new project with expo-cli.

**FIRST**,  run this command -> `expo init projectname`
at this step, select the blank project selection.
then you can see the generated project.

**SECOND**, merge the dependencies. and then run `npm install` or `yarn install`.

**LAST**, run react-native project with `npm start` or `yarn start`.

Comment: @DragonWhilte , Thank you so much for the solution. I have some questions though. 1.Sorry, did not understand the meaning "merge the dependencies". What should I do ? 2. If I create a new project, can I retain the codes I have written in the original project? Please suggest

Comment: blank expo projects have package.json which contains necessary dependencies, so you can copy and paste your package settings and then remove the duplicated.

Comment: then copy and paste your whole code except the package.json.

Comment: then flow the second step.

Comment: thank you. I have done the same but facing new issues. Anyways your answer is helpful